# Why my reputation decreased on Stack Overflow ?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I can not find any proper reason for that. As the reputation Tab is not Showing any red coloured -reputation. Yesterday Night when I logged off it was 157, and on morning it is 153, I want to learn from my mistakes but where I committed it, I can not figure out?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Most likely there were two posts deleted, posts for which you had received +2 for editing.

Comment: in your reputation tab, click on "show deleted post" Then it will show you reputation history for removed post.

Comment: FYI: reputation drops aren't necessarily a bad thing. They can be good (serial voting reversed).